# How to correctly use TS typings with styled-components withComponent()?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I have troubles wrapping my head around using `withComponent()` method of a `StyledComponent` in a Typescript environment. I have a simple styled component which I want to apply on a React component. But the Typescript compiler complains about a props mismatch.

How should I use the `withComponent()` method to get a styled component, which has also the props from my react component?

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const RedBackground = styled.div`
    background-color: red;
`;

interface MenuContainerProps {
    focus?: boolean;
}

class MenuContainer extends React.Component<MenuContainerProps> {
    static defaultProps = {
        focus: true,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>MenuContainer</div>
        );
    }
}

const RedMenuContainer = RedBackground.withComponent(MenuContainer);
//                                       error here  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/*
    Usage of RedMenuContainer. It should have a red `background-color` and a `focus` prop.

    <RedMenuContainer focus={true}>
        ... children ...
    </RedMenuContainer>
*/
```

The error message:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'typeof MenuContainer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>>'.
  Types of property 'defaultProps' are incompatible.
    Type '{ focus: boolean; }' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>>'.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the Styled Component TypeScript types unfortunately.  The workaround for now would be to force the correct resulting type:

```
import styled, { StyledComponentClass } from 'styled-components';

// ...

type StyledRedMenuContainer = StyledComponentClass<MenuContainerProps, any, MenuContainerProps>
const RedMenuContainer = RedBackground.withComponent(MenuContainer as any) as StyledRedMenuContainer;
```

There has been [some work](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/1739) to fix the TypeScript types for `withComponent`, but I believe it may be stalled as for Styled Components 4.0 the TypeScript types are being extracted externally to DefinitelyTyped.

As a side note, your `MenuContainer` in this case would need to accept a `className` prop and pass it to its child `<div>` in order for it to actually pick up the red style.